# show next or previous image onClick Android

Tags: android, imageview

i have 30 images in my project and i want to display 10 of them in a single image view using next and previous button (like a slide show) how do i do that ? thanks!

```
previousButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.backButton);
    previousButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    nextButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nextButton);
    nextButton.setOnClickListener(this);

set image in onclick method

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
if (view == previousButton) {
        --positionOfSelectedImage;
        // set background image of
    } else if (view == nextButton) {
        ++positionOfSelectedImage;
    }

imageToBeSet.setImageURI(Uri.parse(absolutepathOfImage));
}
```

Comment: clear your question first....

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-fullscreen-image-slider-with-swipe-and-pinch-zoom-gestures/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a much more simple way to do that.

Try this code:

```
package com.example.jre;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    Button btprevious, btnext;
    ImageView myImage;
    public int i = 0;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

btprevious = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
btnext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myImage);

btprevious.setOnClickListener(this);
btnext.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

switch (v.getId()){
case R.id.button1:
i++;

if(i==2) // switch to 11 because you got 10 images
{
    i=1; // switch to 10, same reason
}

changeImage();
break;

case R.id.button2:
i--;

if(i==-1)
{
    i=0; // you can leave it this way or improve it later
}

changeImage();
break;
}
}

public void changeImage()
{
    myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myImage);

switch(i)
{

case 0:
myImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.firstimage);
break;

case 1:
myImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.secondimage);
break;
// and then it goes further
}
}

}
```

And in your xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.jre.MainActivity" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/myImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="86dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/myImage"
        android:text="Next" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/myImage"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/myImage"
        android:text="Previous" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

That should do the work!

Comment: invite me to chat please

Comment: hello there friend, i have asked another simple question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27073636/giving-stroke-to-text-view-text-android-hack/27074129#27074129 i would be glad if you take some time and answer it. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

define your images address (eg: R.drawable.xxx) in a `List` and then :

```
List <String> imagePath = new ArrayList<String> ();
imagePath.add("image1Path");
imagePath.add("image2Path");
...
imagePath.add("image30Path");
previousButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.backButton);
previousButton.setOnClickListener(this);

nextButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nextButton);
nextButton.setOnClickListener(this);
myImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

int index = 0;
//show first image in list
myImageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath.get(0)));


@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
if (view.getId() == R.id.backButton) {
        --index;
        // set background image of
    } else if (view.getId() == R.id.nextButton) {
        ++index;
    }

myImageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath.get(index)));
}
```

Comment: please invite me to chat

Answer (score 0):

**make array for images to store all images from drawable also your back and next button and the imageview where you want to preiview all images,and start int n from zero**

```
ImageView previewImg,backImg,nextImg;
int[] mario = new int[]{R.drawable.nature_07,R.drawable.nature_08,R.drawable.nature_09,
        R.drawable.nature_10,R.drawable.nature_11,R.drawable.nature_12,
        R.drawable.nature_13,R.drawable.nature_14
};
int n =0;

**in the oncreate method do it by the following code**
 previewImg = findViewById(R.id.previewImg);
    backImg = findViewById(R.id.backBtn);
    nextImg = findViewById(R.id.nextBtn);

    //your default image to preview when ist time its is open
    previewImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.nature_12);

    nextImg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
         //the n value is 7 cause the array size is 7
            if(n < 7)
                n++;
            previewImg.setImageResource(mario[n]);
        }
    });
    backImg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            previewImg.setImageResource(mario[n]);
            if(n>0)
                n--;
        }
    });
```